# Unable to add and update to dictionary c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am currently making a client and server. The server will store people and their location using a dictionary. The client can then lookup a location or update/add a person and their location.
For example, I could type 'Lucy', 'School', and the server will add that to the dictionary. If I then type 'Lucy' it should reply with 'School' and if I type in 'Lucy' 'Home' it should up date that to the dictionary.

Currently however, it is not adding people to the dictionary or updating their location. The following is my code to run the server, which is called in the main class:

```
static void runServer()
{
    TcpListener listener;
    Socket connection;
    NetworkStream socketStream;
    try
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 43);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server started listening");
        while (true)
        {
            connection = listener.AcceptSocket();
            socketStream = new NetworkStream(connection);
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Recieved.");
            doRequest(socketStream);
            socketStream.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.ToString());
    }
}
```

This part is the `doRequest` method which is called in the `runServer`. This is where I have made my dictionary and tried methods to update and add:

```
static void doRequest(NetworkStream socketStream)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    try
    {
        socketStream.ReadTimeout = 1000;
        socketStream.WriteTimeout = 1000;
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(socketStream);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(socketStream);


        String line = sr.ReadLine().Trim();
        String[] Sections = line.Split(new char[] {' '}, 2);
        if (Sections.Length == 1)
        {
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(Sections[0]))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(dictionary[Sections[0]]);
                sw.Flush();
            }

            else
            {
                sw.WriteLine("ERROR: no entries found");
                sw.Flush();
            }
        }

        else if (Sections.Length == 2)
        {
            try
            {
                if (dictionary.ContainsKey(Sections[0]))
                {
                    dictionary[Sections[0]] = Sections[1];
                    sw.WriteLine("OK");
                    sw.Flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    dictionary.Add(Sections[0], Sections[1]);
                    sw.WriteLine("OK");
                    sw.Flush();
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                sw.WriteLine("DIDNT SAVE");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Too many arguments");
        } 
    }

    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect");
    }
}
```

I've tried various different ways. My first concern was that the dictionary is created in the dorequest method so isn't global, however it doesn't seem to work when I put it somewhere else.
Hopefully it's just a little mistake I've missed.
Any help would be largely appreciated.
Thanks
Lucy

Comment: You are correct that declaring the dictionary in `doReqeust` is part of the problem.  Each time that method is called, a new, empty dictionary instance is created.  One way to remedy this issue would be to instantiate the dictionary in the `runServer` method (prior to the `while` loop), and then pass it into the `doRequest` method as a parameter.

Comment: Just a few quick comments, you can set the streamwriter to auto flush with `sw.AutoFlush = true` which just automatically flushes after each write. Second you should try and return early instead of nesting if statements. You aren't at the "holy shit" stage, but it's good practice. Third, have you thought about using any of the async functions in C#? You can `await sw.WriteLineAsync("my message")` instead of blocking.

Comment: You may have more than one space.  Try this :             String[] Sections = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);